# Cant use db:create when I try to configure CartoDB

Tags: mysql, postgresql, docker, cartodb

When I execute `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:create` I get this:

> rake aborted! No database associated with Sequel::Model: have you called Sequel.connect or Sequel::Mode.db= ?

I tried to execute `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:drop` and I got this:

> rake aborted! Database not configured. Please create config/database.yml or set DATABASE_URL in environment.

I dont see what could be the real problem because I have config/database.yml and is correct because is downloaded from CartoDB and should not give problems.

Even if that should be no problem I deleted the original file and created my own database.yml with  everything defined correctly and the yaml code accepted by an yaml validator.Still gives me the same problems.

I tried executing the command with `DATABASE_URL=/path/to/database.yml/` and got the same problems.

I tried to delete database.yml and got the same errors, like it didnt even matter if it was there or not. This might make you think that I have the files in the wrong place but I tried to execute deleting app_config.yml and got and error that the file is missing. These two have to be in the same folder so I guess the problem is not that one either.

For last I created the database on psql with the name I needed and everything worked after (db:migrate for example). The problem is that I need to create them using the database.yml file and not on my own.

Here is my database.yml file just in case I might have missed something:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  direct_port: 5432
  database: carto_db_production
  username: postgres
  password:
  conn_validator_timeout: 900
  connect_timeout: 2.5
  prepared_statements: false

staging:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  direct_port: 5432
  database: carto_db_staging
  username: postgres
  password:
  conn_validator_timeout: 900
  connect_timeout: 2.5
  prepared_statements: false

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  direct_port: 5432
  database: carto_db_development
  username: postgres
  password:
  conn_validator_timeout: 900
  connect_timeout: 2.5
  pool: 50
  prepared_statements: false

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: carto_db_test
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  direct_port: 5432
  username: postgres
  password:
  conn_validator_timeout: -1
  connect_timeout: -1
  prepared_statements: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a bug on CartoDB and was fixed by them in the last release.